# how to handle object coming from elasticsearch highlight option

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, graphql, nestjs

here is the query for example

```
public highlightingIssue(input: string): Observable<EsJob[] | []>{
    return from(this.elasticJobSearchService.search({
        index: 'jobwildcard',
        size: 250,
        body: {
            query: {
                bool: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            path: "brand",
                            query: {
                                bool: {
                                    should: {
                                        match: {
                                            "brand.name": {
                                                query: input
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            highlight: {
                fields: {
                    "brand.name": {}
                }
            }
        }
    })).pipe(
        map((searchResult: ApiResponse): Record<string, any> => searchResult.body),
        tap((val) => console.log(val)),

        map((body: Record<string, any>) => body.hits.hits),
        switchMap(
            (hits) => {
                if (hits.length < 1) 
                    return of([]);
                }
                return forkJoin(
                    hits.map(
                        (hit) => {
                            return of(hit._source)
                    }
                )
            );
        }),
    )
}
```

hightlight return type is for example as follow

```
"highlight" : {
      "brand.name" : [
        "<em>Nike</em>"
      ]
    }
```

how to make highlight type in graphql

```
@ObjectType("EsHighlight")
export class highlight{
    public "brand.name": string; 
}
```

cant define "brand.name" variable as above, any solution?

```
@ObjectType("EsHighlight")
export class highlight{
    public brandName: string; 
}
```

im for example using above method but its not solving because brandName isnt equal to "brand.name"